# Using GWT in large scale enterprise applications

Tags: gwt, gwt-platform

I'm evaluating to use GWT / GWT-Platform to develop a large scale enterprise application.

Can anybody speak properly about the use of this tools in high demanding environments?

I would thank any kind of contribution.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this : [GWT: Large scale application development and MVP](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/articles/mvp-architecture.html)

Comment: Thanks! I've already read this tutorial. My question is most oriented to know if there's any successful large scale system release and maybe some details about like: amount of tables, screens, functionalities, use cases, etc.

Comment: Personnally I used GWT for a medium sized web application and I never had any issues. I don't see any contre-indication for using it in a high demanding environments... Try asking a new question focused on the demanding enviromnent, and giving more details about what you mean by : high demanding environment. You should be able to find someone that developped an app with similar constraints to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Google uses GWT for their adwords front ends.  This includes the online front end, the tv front end, and numerous other high availability customer facing products.  The tv product alone has several dozen screens, each of which has a whole passel of ajax widgets and editors.

It seem easier to maintain at scale than similar siEd products ibased on jsp that I had worked with in years past.

For that matter, wave was a quite demanding application in term of latency, and gwt kept up.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely scalable to use in large applications.  It's used by Google in several places (previously mentioned).

I also know of at least one large company I worked at that also used GWT to build a large web based application.

Comment: Could you give me some details like amount of functionalities or use cases? What kind of functionalities and for how many users was developed? What about performance, and requirements delivery times?

Comment: I asked you because I would like to know about the global behaviour in web applications with 50 - 100 use cases (screens, pages, whatever)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say GWT is as capable as any other tool that you're likely to use. We use GWT here for a medium-size application with various different modules and so on (built using different Maven module configurations) and it works well. Probably the best out of all the Java style UI solutions I've used.

In general I'd say GWT is definitely ready for a large-scale enterprise application - I'd say it's good to use unless you're doing a public-facing website where accessibility is a concern!